# Как заменить стандартную метку на своё изображение в Конструкторе карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-embed

Как в Яндекс картах заменить стандартную метку на логотип компании, не прибегая к программированию (через конструктор карты)?

Comment: Какую метку? Какие карты? О каком API вообще речь идет?

Comment: Метки на Яндекс картах

Comment: Похоже через конструктор можно указать только заранее заданные иконки.

Answer (score 1):

Через Конструктор карт можно создать только карту со стандартными элементами и стилями. Кастомизировать иконку не получится - нужен JS API.

Comment: Спасибо..я читал у них в документации что теги изображений не работают, думал может какая лазейка есть